# How can we insert the result of MongoDB aggregate query to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I have a query like this, and need to store the result of this query into a SQL Server database.

```
db.Records.aggregate(
{ $group : {
    _id :  { Date:'$Info.ActualDate',Country:'$Info.country'},
         "RecordCount": { "$sum": 1 },
}} 
);
```

Please guide me how to make it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to make a separate call from your app to SQL Server to insert the data you retrieve from MongoDB. There is no inter-database connectivity.

Comment: Seems there might actually be:  http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DGA/odbc/pg_linkedsrv.htm

Comment: That is creating a link from SQL Server to MongoDB (something I would never recommend, but I digress). The OP is trying to go the other direction, pushing aggregation data to SQL Server.